# Clonezilla can't see folder for restore disk

Tags: clonezilla

I'm switching from 1TB classic hard disk to SSD

I made a disk image to an external USB drive. I can see the folder and the files within it. However when I run Clonezilla again, the folder does not show at all for restoring. This is independent of what disk is in my laptop.

Viewing the filesystem, the folder seems to be there though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clonezilla doesn't display folder names that contain spaces.

Replace the spaces with dashes or underscores in the names of folders which contain your image files and you should be fine.

Comment: Do you have any source for this information? Seems quite fishy...

Comment: I had the same problem.I noticed that none of my folder names containing spaces appear in Clonezilla. I resolved the issue as described. Try it yourself.